# AppEngine: Geospatial queries under Go

Tags: google-app-engine, go, geospatial, geo

There appears to be geospatial-query support under Java (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/geosearch) but there appears to be absolutely no documentation for doing the same under Go. Grepping google.golang.org/appengine for "geo" renders nothing but construction and validation of *GeoPoint* values.

Since Java supports this the API support must obviously be there. Does anyone have any experience with this or advice? Thanks.

Edit:

It looks like what limited support there is is only offered for Java:

http://startup-with-gae.blogspot.com/2016/01/geospatial-queries-with-google-cloud.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's, officially, completely unsupported in Datastore at this time. Use geohashes: https://github.com/gansidui/geohash/blob/master/geohash.go . It reduces this fro ma geospatial-storage/RTREE support problem to a string prefix-search.

It allows you derive a hash that describes a particular location, and then you can take this string and successively remove characters from the right side (and do string prefix-searches against your list of places and *their* geohashes with what remains) to find places near your principal location and expanding outward.

There is a predictable amount of geographic precision between each adjacent character of a geohash string, so you can either use this or the common prefix bytes between the principal point and the corner latitude/longitude of the map window to identify all places that should appear within it.